# Extract and merge lists from dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = { 'a': ['a','b','c'],
            'x': ['x','y','z'] }
```

What is the simplest way to extract and merge the lists to get: `['a','b','c','x','y','z']` ?

**Edit:** the result can be in arbitrary order and we can assume the lists' elements are unique.

Comment: You haven't specified the rule that determines the final order.  Is it "loop over the keys in sorted order and combine the lists", or is it "combine the lists however you like into one list and then sort that"?

Comment: Is the order of the values important?

Comment: Do all your kictionary values have unique entries? THe solutions below do not check for duplicate entries and that would requires an extra step once the final list has been generated. For example, what if 'a' is an entry in the lists for keys 'y' and 'z' What would you want to see?

Comment: Once again, "no need to sort the elements" doesn't settle the issue.  Is `["x', "y", "z", "a", "b", "c"]` an okay answer too?

Comment: DSM: Yes, that result is okay.

Comment: @bsdnoobz: please edit that into your question so that it's clear the order is arbitrary.

Comment: @bsnoobz is an answer ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a'] also satisfactory if 'a' is an element under more than one key?

Comment: @sabbahillel that would be unacceptable. but we shouldn't worry about that since the elements of the lists are guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print [v for k in my_dict for v in my_dict[k]]
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Simply iterate over the keys and then over the values, like this, to produce the list using list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

```
[v for val in my_dict.itervalues() for v in val]
```

Answer (score 3):

Short and concise:

```
sum(my_dict.values(), [])
```

**Update:**

This solution is elegant, however bears quadratic time complexity. If you expect large input data other solutions posted would be preferrable.

Comment: The OP has now made it clear that order isn't important, but recommending people use a quadratic algorithm because of simplicity isn't a good policy, I don't think.

Comment: Another point would be what does the OP want to happen if an element value is found under more than one key. Do both go into the final output or only one. Example 'a' is an element of keys 'y' and 'z'

Comment: @DSM Agreed. I added a note about time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one very simple, but not optimal, way:

```
my_dict = { 'a': ['a','b','c'],
            'x': ['x','y','z'] }

l = []
for key in my_dict:
    for element in my_dict[key]:
        l.append(element)

print l

>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: You might want to say if element not in l: l.append(element) depending on what is desired as final output.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict = { 'a': ['a','b','c'],
            'x': ['x','y','z'] }
```

You can iterate through all keys of your dictionary and add the corresponding values to the final list. Like this:

```
my_list = []
for key in my_dict.keys():
    my_list += my_dict[key]
```